# SQL Server 2014 performances : logical reads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlperformance, logical-reads

New focus : What parameters can have an impact on "number of logical reads" ?

UAT and PROD environments are supposed to be the same but "number of logical reads" is huge for PROD.

[image]

[Exec plans on UAT & PROD](http://www.cjoint.com/data/FKvqlQD1w5U_PROD-UAT-exec-plans.7z)

[Detailed problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680403/sql-server-2014-different-performances-huge-number-of-executions-with-same/40682338#40682338) => Not solved

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server 2014: different performances (huge "number of executions") with same VMs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680403/sql-server-2014-different-performances-huge-number-of-executions-with-same)